# ASP.NET Core and 102 status code implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

I have long operation, which called via Web API. Status code 102 says to us:

> An interim response used to inform the client that the server has
> accepted the complete request, but has not yet completed it.
>
> This status code SHOULD only be sent when the server has a reasonable
> expectation that the request will take significant time to complete.
> As guidance, if a method is taking longer than 20 seconds (a
> reasonable, but arbitrary value) to process the server SHOULD return a
> 102 (Processing) response. The server MUST send a final response after
> the request has been completed.

So, I want to return 102 status code to client, then client waits response about result of operation. How to implement it on .NET?

I read this thread: [How To Return Http 102 Processing in Asp.Net Web Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362899/how-to-return-http-102-processing-in-asp-net-web-api)

This thread has good explanation what is necessary, but no response. I don't understand how it implement on .NET, not theory...

Comment: Did you saw this - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/316211/1706

Comment: @Anuraj yes, I saw. Where is concrete implementation there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTTP 102 requires that the server send two responses for one request. ASP.NET (Core or not) does not support sending a response to the client without completely ending the request. Any attempt to send two responses will end up in throwing an exception and just not working. (I tried a couple different ways)

There's a good discussion [here](https://evertpot.com/http/102-processing) about how it's not actually in the HTTP spec, so implementing it isn't really required.

There are a couple alternatives I can think of:

1. Use web sockets (a persistent connection that allows data to be sent back and forth), like with SignalR, for example.
2. If your request takes a long time because it's getting data from elsewhere, you can try pulling in that data via a stream and send it to the client via a stream. That will send the data as it's coming in, rather than loading it all into memory first before sending it. Here's an example of streaming data from a database to the response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45682190/1202807